Cant integrate ZStack SampleLight Project with Home Assistant (ZHA)
Over the past few months (with some breaks), I've been working on creating my own "Light" that I can integrate into Home Assistant using a Sonoff Dongle 3.0. For the microcontroller, I chose the CC2530. My initial goal was simply to turn an LED on and off via Home Assistant. However, when I attempt to search for devices in Home Assistant, it does not detect the CC2530 running the Sample Light project from Z-Stack 3.0.2.
I have ensured that the PAN ID and the communication channel are correctly configured and match between devices. Despite this, the CC2530 still isn't being detected. I've consulted the Z-Stack documentation and made numerous attempts with help from ChatGPT, Copilot, and other resources, but I seem to be missing a crucial step.
I did explore the PTVO firmware, which works and allows me to connect to Home Assistant. However, because the PSM modes in PTVO firmware require a paid license, I would prefer to create the solution from scratch. Additionally, I have other plans that involve writing specific operations into the code.
I hesitated to post on a forum because I thought it might be a "simple" issue, but now I feel I need some guidance.
Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.
